# setting up a modal dialog in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm creating a form using `javascript` which is actually a modal dialog. 
I'm having trouble figuring out how to attach an `id` tag when I try to set it up.
This is how I'm creating the line in js

```
tmpString += "<div id=\"dialog-modal\" class=\"widget-dialog-container\" title=\"Complete Your Order\">";
...
...
var handle = document.getElementById('content');
handle.innerHTML = tmpString;
```

Now I'm trying to access it this way

```
$(document).dialog( {
        height: 800,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
});
```

I do know that I have to have `$(document)` because the dialog is being created in code. but I don't know how to give it the `#dialog-modal` so I can access it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your popup like this

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog( {
        height: 800,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
});
```

at any time use

```
 $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
```

to open it.

Dynamic html popup append

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tmpString =  "<div id=\"dialog-modal\" class=\"widget-dialog-container\" title=\"Complete Your Order\">";
    var handle = document.getElementById('content');
    handle.innerHTML = tmpString;

    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        height: 800,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't working and I'm guessing it's because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490657/cant-execute-javascript-on-dynamically-created-html-button?rq=1

Comment: No you can alse append Html dynamically and use popup. but you need to confirm that use popup bind after append html.

Comment: You first have to append your html. then bind dialog function.